# Is it possible to transfer a folder from GCS to Bigquery using Java API

Tags: java, api, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, data-transfer

When I tried to give the source URI of a folder inside my bucket (which has around 400 CSV files) in the Java program, it has not moved any files to BQ table. If I try with a single csv file , it moves.

```
package com.example.bigquerydatatransfer;

import com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiException;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.CreateTransferConfigRequest;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.DataTransferServiceClient;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.ProjectName;
import com.google.cloud.bigquery.datatransfer.v1.TransferConfig;
import com.google.protobuf.Struct;
import com.google.protobuf.Value;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

// Sample to create google cloud storage transfer config
public class Cloud_to_BQ {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    final String projectId = "dfp-bq";
    String datasetId = "mytest1";
    String tableId = "PROG_DATA";
    
    String sourceUri = "gs://dfp-bq/C:\\PROG_Reports";
    String fileFormat = "CSV";
    String fieldDelimiter = ",";
    String skipLeadingRows = "1";
    Map<String, Value> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put(
        "destination_table_name_template", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(tableId).build());
    params.put("data_path_template", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(sourceUri).build());
    params.put("write_disposition", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue("APPEND").build());
    params.put("file_format", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(fileFormat).build());
    params.put("field_delimiter", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(fieldDelimiter).build());
    params.put("skip_leading_rows", Value.newBuilder().setStringValue(skipLeadingRows).build());
    TransferConfig transferConfig =
        TransferConfig.newBuilder()
            .setDestinationDatasetId(datasetId)
            .setDisplayName("Trial_Run_PROG_DataTransfer")
            .setDataSourceId("google_cloud_storage")
            .setParams(Struct.newBuilder().putAllFields(params).build())
            .setSchedule("every 24 hours")
            .build();
    createCloudStorageTransfer(projectId, transferConfig);
  }

  public static void createCloudStorageTransfer(String projectId, TransferConfig transferConfig)
      throws IOException {
    try (DataTransferServiceClient client = DataTransferServiceClient.create()) {
      ProjectName parent = ProjectName.of(projectId);
      CreateTransferConfigRequest request =
          CreateTransferConfigRequest.newBuilder()
              .setParent(parent.toString())
              .setTransferConfig(transferConfig)
              .build();
      TransferConfig config = client.createTransferConfig(request);
      System.out.println("Cloud storage transfer created successfully :" + config.getName());
    } catch (ApiException ex) {
      System.out.print("Cloud storage transfer was not created." + ex.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way I can move all the files to the BQ table at a stretch?

2022-08-04T07:27:50.185847509ZNo files found matching: "gs://dfp-bq/C:\PROG_Reports" - This is the BQ logs for the Run.

Comment: Show us the code.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov Have added the code in description.

Comment: "every 24 hours" means it'll likely start at "00:00" in the next day after you created the transfer. How long did you wait before you concluded that your code doesn't work?

Comment: @M. Prokhorov
after the first run , from the Run details in BQ data trasnfer logs that it has not found any files from the path I gave.

Comment: This may help: instead of just passing the uri for the folder you should pass a wildcard like `String sourceUri = "gs://dfp-bq/C:\\PROG_Reports/*";` (note the `*` at the end). See [Wildcard support for Cloud Storage URIs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/batch-loading-data#load-wildcards).

Comment: @99_m4n,Tried this. didnt help. It works in the UI , but from the code it didnt.